# mac apache start in a terminal failed

Tags: macos, apache, terminal

I want to start Apache in Mac. If I make web sharing enable by checking in `system prefs -> web sharing`, Apache works. But if I input command in terminal: `sudo apachectl start`, Apache  doesn't start. In this case, when run `http://localhost` in Safari, it always said `The requested URL / was not found on this server.` In both cases, I used the default `httpd.conf`.

Therefore, How can I start Apache and make it work in Mac by inputting command in a terminal instead of by the graphical config window of mac itself? I prefer to command in a terminal.

Thank you.

Comment: Not exactly a programming question but....  Look at the file "error_log" in the /var/log/apache2 directory and see if there are any hints.

Comment: Following are words from `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` in mac: `# Generally, desktop has no vhosts and server does; server has added modules,
# custom virtual hosts are only activated when Web Service is on, and
# default document root and personal web sites at ~username are only
# activated when Web Sharing is on.` From the words, in mac, if I start apache in terminal, it won't work. What Mac's Web Sharing does is different from the command `sudo apachectl start`? From my experience in Linux, they should be same. Feel curiosity to mac!

Comment: I just checked /var/log/apache2/error_log. If I started apache by `system prefs -> web sharing` of mac's config window, no error was in the log. If started apache by `sudo apachectl start` in terminal, one error in the log is `[error] [client 192.168.1.2] File does not exist: /usr/htdocs`. The point is why using same `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` resulted in a different situation: one succeeded and the other failed.

Answer (score 1):

Figure it out. The point is from the words of **/etc/apache2/httpd.conf**:

`The <IfDefine> blocks segregate server-specific directives
and also directives that only apply when Web Sharing or
server Web Service (as opposed to other services that need Apache) is on.
The launchd plist sets appropriate Define parameters.`

The action of **Web Sharing** in mac (system prefs -> web sharing) in nature first launches `plist` to set appropriate `Define` parameters, then calls `apachectl`. If we read httpd.conf, we can find the file is structured in several sections -- `<IfDefine xxxx>yyyyy</IfDefine>` based on the parameters from plist.

If we call the command `sudo apachectl start` in terminal like what we usually do in linux, the Define parameters from plist can't be set. Although httpd is up, it is not configured appropriately, e.g., in my case, `DocumentRoot` is not set at all because the parameter is surrounded by

```
<IfDefine !MACOSXSERVER>
<IfDefine WEBSHARING_ON>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>
```

This is why the error log said `[error] [client 192.168.1.2] File does not exist: /usr/htdocs`. As to /usr/htdocs, it is not set in any configure file but is hardcoded in Apache. It is the "last resort" place to look for.

If we comment `#<IfDefine !MACOSXSERVER>` and `#<IfDefine WEBSHARING_ON>` and the two `#</IfDefine>`, call `sudo apachectl start` in terminal. Then everything is ok.

It took me a full day of work to finally straighten this out. I hope it is useful to those guys who are used to be Linux and especially prefer to command line in terminal like me and just move to Mac.